# Isolate 2 variables in 2 formulas

Tags: functions

I am developing a robotic arm and I need to know the angles of $2$ parts of this arm (bars) and I have $2$ variables with $2$ formulas and I tried my best and I still cant isolate those $2$ variables.

In the formulas below, $[A,B,C,D]$ are constants, and $[x,y]$ are variables in degrees (not radians):

- $A\cdot\cos{x}-B=A\cdot\sin{y-90}$
- $C\cdot\cos{Y-90}--A\cdot\sin{X}=D$

How can I isolate $x$ and $y$?

I tried my best and I ended up with a big $\arccos$ with $\sin$ inside which had also another $\cos$ inside which I could not work with it anymore and keep isolating.

EDIT:

Thank you for the person who edited this question and made if more readable, I am not used to MATHEXCHANGE sintax.

I also would like to complement this question saying that I really need to isolate X and Y cause I am using an Arduino microcontoller which is not powerful and not good for an iterative process to solve this equations.

**FINAL EDIT:
A REALLY NICE GUY HELPED ME WITH THIS in this thread -> [How to get alfa and beta from this image](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907722/how-to-get-alfa-and-beta-from-this-image) and there he solved this problem with a very creative alternative.**

Comment: are the angles in degrees?

Comment: @Dr. Sonnhard Graubner yes the angles are in degrees as said at the end of second paragraph :)

Comment: Hint: `sin(Y - 90)=-cos(Y)`, `cos(Y - 90)=sin(Y)`. Eliminate Y via `sin(Y)^2+cos(Y)^2=1`.

Comment: @Aretino I tried using many trigomonoetry identities and I was not good enough to discover what you said!!! I will try to simplify the formula now but will be waiting if any of you can still help me :)

Answer (score 1):

If the angles are in degrees, you are in luck!

Remember, $$\cos(y-90^\circ) = \sin(y)\\
\sin(y-90^\circ)=-\cos(y)$$

So, your equations become

$$A\cos x + C\sin y = B\\
C\sin y - A\sin x = D$$

You can now use $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x$ and then first extract $\sin y$ (and out of that, $y$).

Comment: Hi Sir, I used your good tip and I so far got this in the first equation: X =  acos((-C x cos (Y)/L1). But if I replace this in the second equation I will have sin of acos of cos which I have no idea how to get Y out of this equation!

Comment: @Samul Just extract $\sin y$ out of the first equation and insert it into the second one.

Comment: I tried what you said right now and still when I isolate Y I get and equation with sen of acos of cos of Y and I cant get Y out of this trigonometry functions!

Answer (score 0):

simplifying the system you will get
$$a\cos(x)=b-a\cos(y)$$
and 
$$a\sin(x)=c\sin(y)-d$$
thus you will get
$$a^2=(b-\cos(y))^2+(c\sin(y)-d)^2$$
can you prceed?
using the $$tan$$ half angle formulas we get
$${a}^{2}-{b}^{2}+2\,{\frac {b \left( 1- \left( \tan \left( y/2 \right) 
 \right) ^{2} \right) }{1+ \left( \tan \left( y/2 \right)  \right) ^{2
}}}-{\frac { \left( 1- \left( \tan \left( y/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 1+ \left( \tan \left( y/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \right) ^{2}}}-4\,{\frac {{c}^{2} \left( \tan \left( y/2 \right) 
 \right) ^{2}}{ \left( 1+ \left( \tan \left( y/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}
 \right) ^{2}}}+4\,{\frac {c\tan \left( y/2 \right) d}{1+ \left( \tan
 \left( y/2 \right)  \right) ^{2}}}-{d}^{2}
=0$$

Comment: Great, it got much simpler! But I still have to isolate Y cause I am using a microcontoller to compute X and Y so I need to isolate both variables. Your third equation is really good but if I expand the square and use sinx2 + cosx2 = 1 it still does not get easy to solve.

Comment: no it is easy you can use the $$tan$$ halfe angle formulas

Comment: your comment came out unformatted. Could you, please, check it so I can read it? I appreciate your attention.

Comment: Nice job man, you did a really good formula manipulation! I simulated a few values in my HP 50G calculator and your formula matches and work perfectly, but... I still have no way to isolate y explicitly :(. Is there any online tool which allows me to isolate these variables?

Comment: I used an online tool and I could isolate Y could you please confirm if this is right? http://www.wolframalpha.com/widgets/view.jsp?id=4acbedbe977480d19b7b682d4878cae2