# How to get alfa and beta from this image

Tags: functions, trigonometry, robotics

I developed a robotic arm with 2 bars. I would like to move this robotic arm to a X,Y coordinate. In order to do that I can set "alfa" and "beta" angles in the motor so they move the arm to the position I want. The problem is that I came up with 2 equations and 2 variables (alfa ($\alpha$) and beta($\beta$)) and I tried really hard but I still can't isolate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ so I can calculate it's value directly, using a microcontoller.

The robotic arm is like this:

[image]

I got these equations:

$$    L_1 \cdot \cos(\alpha) + L_2 \cdot \cos(\beta) = y$$
$$    L_2 \cdot \sin(\beta) - L_1 \cdot \sin(\alpha) = x$$

I tried many methods, many trigonometry identities but still couldn't isolate $\alpha$ and $\beta$ in terms of $L_1, L_2, x$ and $y$.

I appreciate all your attention. If you want to see the robotic arm that I am trying to build, it will look like this image below:

[image]

It's basically 2 bars that you can control 2 angles and move it to exact positions.

Comment: Maybe it's easier to find the joint position findind the intersection of the circles centered in $(0, 0)$ and $(x, y)$.

Comment: @N74 any idea how to do that? i didnt understand very well

Comment: What should the robotic arm be doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were building this robot, instead of $\beta,$ I would use the angle that the two arms form relative to one another.  That way as $\alpha$ changes you don't need to keep recalculating $\beta$.

I will call it $\gamma$.  We can find it using the law of cosines

$x^2 + y^2 = L_1^2 + L_2^2 - 2 L_1 L_2 \cos \gamma$

$\beta = \pi - \alpha - \gamma$

Two more angles.

Lets imagine that there is a line from the origin to (x,y) closing up the triangle.

Let $\phi$ be angle at the origin.

$L_2^2 = x^2 + y^2 + L_1^2 - 2\sqrt{x^2+y^2}L_1 \cos\phi$

$\theta = \tan^{-1} \frac {y}{x}$ is the angle between the straight line from the origin to $(x,y)$ and the $x$ axis.

$\theta + \phi = 90 + \alpha$

And that should be enough tools to get you everything you need.

Comment: I totally agree with your first paragraph but my motors ask me to set them alfa and beta, not the angle between the bars (which is a great idea from yours, thank you). I read 3 times what you said and I understood only the first part (law of cosines) but I couldnt understand the final part. Anyway, at the end you present a final equation but I cant understand how that helps me to get alfa and beta explicitly. My english is not good and I am brazilian that's why probably I didnt understand what your said, and it also lacks me a good math too.

Comment: I programmed in my software exactly what you said but I think angles are not matching and I am even having math erros like the content of the first "acos" being biger than 1 when X =10 and Y=10 and L1=7 and L2 = 6.. Working with your great solution I came to this: float alfa = atan(y/x) + acos((L2^2 - x^2 - y^2 - L1^2)/(L1*sqrt(x^2 + y^2))) - PI/2;     AND       float beta = PI - alfa - acos(-1*(x^2 + y^2 - L1^2 - L2^2)/(2*L1*L2));

Comment: I think  "β=180−α−γ" as you posted is correct cause the sum of the angles of that triangle should be 180. Are you sure "γ=α+β" is correct?

Comment: Right, right, but... just programmed this on my side and dropped a minus sign, and that rotated $\gamma$  180 degrees.  Found the error.  Law of cosines (I did it correctly the first time but not the second.) $c^2 = a^2 + b^2 - 2ab \cos C, \alpha = atan (y/x) + acos (\frac {x^2 + y^2 + L1^2 - L2^2}{2L1\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})-\frac {\pi}{2}$

Comment: I finally tested a lot your equations and they worked fine. Man, I appreciate a lot your kindness and attention into this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Ok first part will be very similar to the previous answer you already got from @Doug.

We want to build a triangle where the sides are $L_1,L_2,\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Add $\gamma$ to mean "leftmost" angle in triangle. We then have thanks to parallell lines that

$$\beta+\alpha+\gamma = \pi \Leftrightarrow \gamma = \pi-\alpha-\beta$$

$\gamma$ can be determined directly from cosine law and the sides. Then we need one more degree of freedom.

We can rewrite your second equation like this:

$$\sin(\beta) = \left(\frac{x+L_1\sin(\alpha)}{L_2}\right)$$
And then rewrite the gamma formula:
$$\sin(\beta) = \sin(\pi-\alpha-\gamma)$$

Now you can combine these and use addition formula for sine a few times to solve for $\sin(\alpha)$. Once you have $\sin(\alpha)$ just plug it back in to get $\sin(\beta)$ and which quadrant should be obvious from these values.

Comment: thank you, at this moment I am testing Doug solution to see if it works fine. Anyway, with Doug solution he could explicitly isolate X and Y. With your approach I cant do that, I would need and iterative process to try to get X and Y.

Comment: But you already knew x and y? Then you would not need to isolate them.

Comment: Sorry I mean alfa and delta sir. I need to isolate alfa and beta. Really sorry for saying X and Y. X and Y I already have, as you said.